# drop_duplicates when using read_json and read_sql_table

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to compare duplicates between two DataFrames, I can do this with:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

I'm having an issue with the actual DataFrames, one DataFrame is coming from `read_sql_table` and another from `read_json`. It seems the DataFrame coming from `read_json` contains an index which isn't present in the `read_sql_table` DataFrame. How can I `drop_duplicates` between these two DataFrames?